# Python: Create a list of tuples from file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a test file that I would like to load the create a list of tuples using the data on the file. The data on the file is as follows> how would I successfully load the file then create tuples.

```
ocean,4
-500, -360
-500, 360
500, 360
500,-360
```

Comment: What do you want your tuples to look like?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I would like them to look like a list

Comment: Please post the expected output for the given input file

Answer (score 0):

A very straightforward way would be to use the `csv` module.  E.g.:

```
import csv

filename = "input.csv"

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: In Python 3, the file must be open with `newline=''` argument -- see https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.reader Also, in Python 3, the unicode strings are used. Because of that it may be importat to use also the `encoding` argument of the `open` function.

Comment: The arguments `newline` and `encoding`, while useful or recommended, are not mandatory, though.

Comment: ... unless you are working on Windows where `\r\n` is used as line ends. And possibly on Mac where `\r` was used as line ends (probably not on the newer unix-based system).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to parse the file:

```
import csv

output = []
with open('input_file') as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        output.append(tuple(row))

print output
```

This returns a list of tuples, each tuple corresponding to every line in the input file.

```
[('ocean', '4'), ('-500', ' -360'), ('-500', ' 360'), ('500', ' 360'), ('500', '-360')]
```

Comment: For Python 2, the input file must be opened in binary mode -- see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader