# Python: Create a Map (tuple) from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with the following data.

```
river,4
-500, -360
-500, 360
500, 360
500,-360

sand, 3
400, 300
500, 300
200, 100
```

My question is I need to take this file load it and create a `tuple` that looks like the following:

```
block=("river",4,(-500, -360),(-500, 360),(500, 360),(500,-360)), ("sand", 3,(400,300), (500, 300), (200, 100))
```

This is my code so far

```
file=open("file.txt", "r")
lineString=file.readlines()
```

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. I have reedited the file

Comment: what about the `4` after the `river` in your input data? Is that material or not?

Comment: in that case how is it not featured in `block`?

Comment: i wanted test it first to make sure this runs first without the 4. You can include the 4 if you want

Comment: People do not downvote for no reason. If you keep asking questions to ones similar to ones you have already asked like here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157511/python-create-a-list-of-tuples-from-file and not giving a feedback there, expect us to downvote.

Comment: Given that you haven't bothered to adopt the answers given on that previous question, why should anyone bother to answer this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
import csv

output = []
block = ()
with open('input_file') as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        output.append(tuple(row))

first_element = output[0]
a, b, c, d = output[1:]
block = (first_element[0], a, b, c, d)
```

prints

```
("river",(-500, -360),(-500, 360),(500, 360),(500,-360))
```

I must say your way of organizing the data makes no sense to me. The above code will work only when there are 4 lines after `river, 4` line. If there are more replace:

```
a, b, c, d = output[1:]
block = (first_element[0], a, b, c, d)
```

with

```
block = (first_element[0], output[1:])
```

But in this case the output will be:

```
("river",[(-500, -360),(-500, 360),(500, 360),(500,-360)])
```

Comment: too many values to unpack on a,b,c,d = output[1:]

Comment: @drunkenmaster My solution was strictly aimed at your example above where there are 4 values. Check my updated answer to know why